# Regular expression to extract content from outer square bracket

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in the following format:

```
TSHIRT[SIZE[S,M,L], COLOR[BLUE,RED,GREEN]]
```

What is the regular expression to extract the properties for tshirt from the outer square bracket ie.

```
SIZE[S,M,L]
COLOR[BLUE,RED,GREEN]
```

Comment: what you have tried so far ? please post the pattern you've tried

Comment: I tried (\\[.*(?:\\[??[^\\[]*?\\])) but it does not give me the group separately. I need SIZE[S, M, L]  and COLOR[BLUE, RED, GREEN] separately

Comment: how about this [`(?<=TSHIRT\[)([^\[]+\[[^\]]+\])[,\s]+([^\[]+\[[^\]]+\])(?=\])`](https://regex101.com/r/YiLd60/1/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex

```
(?<=TSHIRT\[)([^\[]+\[[^\]]+\])[,\s]+([^\[]+\[[^\]]+\])(?=\])
```

- `(?<=TSHIRT)` - Match must be preceded by `TSHIRT`
- `([^\[]+\[[^\]]+\])` - Capture group to capture the desired values

  - `[^\[]+` - Match anything except `[` one or more time
  - `\[`     - Match `[`
  - `[^\]]+` - Match anything except `]` one or more time
  - `\]` - Match `]`
- `[,\s]+` - Match `, or space` characters
- `(?=\])` - Match must be followed by `]`

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/YiLd60/1/)

Comment: this is not creating 2 groups.I want SIZE[S,M,L]     and  COLOR[BLUE,RED,GREEN] in 2 group so that i can get the size and color of tshirt.

Comment: @YogeshTyagi did you seen the regex demo ? it does create two groups, click on the match information block and on the link i provided and see it does create two groups

Comment: @YogeshTyagi [`Match information`](https://ibb.co/jLvDwpt)

Comment: It is working.Thanks a lot for your assistance so nice of you.:-)

Comment: not working for TSHIRT[SIZE[S,M,L]], it should return me 1 group

Comment: (?<=TSHIRT\[)([^\[]+\[[^\]]+\])[\s,\s]*([^\[]+\[[^\]]+\])?(?=\])  this is working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
SIZE\[([^\]]*)\]|COLOR\[([^\]]*)\]
```

might simply return those size and color values.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/al7qiv/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "SIZE\\[([^\\]]*)\\]|COLOR\\[([^\\]]*)\\]";
        final String string = "TSHIRT[SIZE[S,M,L], COLOR[BLUE,RED,GREEN]]\n"
             + "TSHIRT[SIZE[S,M,L,XL,XXL], COLOR[BLUE,RED,GREEN,PINK,ORANGE]]";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: SIZE[S,M,L]
Group 1: S,M,L
Group 2: null
Full match: COLOR[BLUE,RED,GREEN]
Group 1: null
Group 2: BLUE,RED,GREEN
Full match: SIZE[S,M,L,XL,XXL]
Group 1: S,M,L,XL,XXL
Group 2: null
Full match: COLOR[BLUE,RED,GREEN,PINK,ORANGE]
Group 1: null
Group 2: BLUE,RED,GREEN,PINK,ORANGE
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/al7qiv/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/al7qiv/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---